# How to write a function that takes an operator as argument with default values?

Tags: c++, operator-keyword, function-templates

I want to write a function template with an optional parameter in the type of function pointer, with default value being `operator+`. If the function is called on objects with `operator+` defined, then the default is used. If the function is called on objects without predefined `operator+`, then the caller can specify a function to do the addition. Here is an example of what I want to do:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename T, typename fun=std::plus<T>>
T addT(T t1, T t2, fun f = {}) {
    return f(t1, t2);
}

int main()
{
    double a = 1., b= 2.;
    auto c = addT(a, b);  // use default value of std::plus
    std::cout<<c<<std::endl;
    
    using vec_int = std::vector<int>;
    vec_int x = {1,1}, y = {2,2};
    auto vec_int_add = [](vec_int x, vec_int y){
        vec_int res;
        std::transform(x.begin(), x.end(), y.begin(), std::back_inserter(res), [](int x, int y){return x+y;});
        return res;
    };
    auto z = addT(x, y, vec_int_add);  // supply a lambda as argument 
    std::cout<<z[0]<<','<<z[1]<<std::endl;
}
```

The issue is that the default value `std::plus` only works if the two arguments are of the same type as the example above. I want the default value to be a function with arguments of two different types, such as this:

```cpp
template<typename T>
T default_add(T x, double y) {
    T res = x + y;
    return res
}
```

I am a bit lost as to how to do this.

Comment: Can't you just add an overload with two arguments? `template <typename T1, typename T2>
auto addT(T1 t1, T2 t2) {
    return t1 + t2;
}`

Comment: You could try constraining `fun` (if you work with `c++20`) so that `requires(T a, T b, fun f) { f(a,b) } -> std::same_as<T>}` or something like that. You can also extend this vastly, depending on your needs. You can also just cast the second parameter to `T`, but that might be bad depending on the things you want to do

Answer (score 3):

In C++14, you might use [`std::plus<void>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/plus_void)

```
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename fun = std::plus<void>>
auto addT(T1 t1, T2 t2, fun f = {}) {
    return f(t1, t2);
}
```

[Demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/TM5n64Kdn)

Answer (score 2):

Just have an overload with two arguments.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

template<typename T1, typename T2>
auto addT(T1 t1, T2 t2) {
    return t1 + t2;
}

template <typename T, typename fun = std::plus<T>> // but is this really needed?
T addT(T t1, T t2, fun f) {
    return f(t1, t2);
}

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename fun>
auto addT(T1 t1, T2 t2, fun f) {
    return f(t1, t2);
}

int main(){
    addT(1, 2);
    addT(1, 2.0); // returns promoted common type, double
    addT(1, 2, [](int a, int b) { return a * b; });
    addT(1.0, 2, [](double a, int b) { return a / b; });
}
```

Comment: You might consider using `std::invoke` (C++17 and up) in `addT` instead of regular call, then it will also work easily for member functions.

Comment: @JeJo your code would result in `addT(1, 2.0)` returning an `int`. Och, I see, but maybe it is OPs requirement.

Comment: @JeJo: `std::commont_type` misplaced, as `addT(1, 0.5)` returns `1.`, you probably want [that](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/4rWE7bj97)

Answer (score 1):

Replace `std::plus<T>` by your own functor which does adding and can accept **two** distinct types:

```
struct Adder {
    template<class T1, class T2>
    auto operator()(T1 v1, T2 v2) const noexcept { return v1 + v2; }
};

template <typename T, typename T2, typename fun=Adder>
auto addT(T t1, T2 t2, fun f = {}) {
    return f(t1, t2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```cpp
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename fun=std::plus<T>>
T1 addT(T1 t1, T2 t2, fun f = {}) {
    return f(t1, (T1)t2);
}
```

This is not very nice as you might have some type that has `operator+` overloaded for an other type, but that type is not cast-able to the first type. You can narrow it with concepts, like:

```cpp
#include <concepts>

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename fun=std::plus<T>>
requires std::convertible_to<T2,T1>
T1 addT(T1 t1, T2 t2, fun f = {}) {
    return f(t1, (T1)t2);
}
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename fun>
requires requires(T1 t1, T2 t2, fun f) {
    { f(t1,t2) } -> std::same_as<T1>;
}
T1 addT(T1 t1, T2 t2, fun f = {}) {
    return f(t1, t2);
}
```

This way you would keep the generality some way. The overload resolution might get a little messy, though so you might want to include:

```cpp
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename fun>
requires std::convertible_to<T2,T1> && requires(T1 t1, T2 t2, fun f) {
    { f(t1,t2) } -> std::same_as<T1>;
}
T1 addT(T1 t1, T2 t2, fun f = {}) {
    return f(t1, t2);
}
```

So that if both constraints are satisfied, no casting is done.